# MYSQL query to pull data even if no date is specified via php

Tags: php, mysql, date

My Goal is to spit out the data in my fields based on a date via a query.  My table consists of 9 Fields, one of them being DATE.

```
DATE      5STAR   4STAR   3STAR   2STAR   1STAR   TOTAL
2/9/2012    94       30     7       4       10     145
2/11/2012   95       31     7       4       10     147
2/12/2012   95       31     8       4       10     148
```

Here's the kicker.  If there is NO DATE such as "2/10/2012" I want to spit out the data in php that is based off the most recent date, so I would spit out data for "2/9/2012" if they selected "2/10/2012".

Any suggestions for a query or do I have to upload all these dates to my database?

Comment: Just get the records ordered by DATE; ie. less than or equal to the date you want, and return LIMIT 1; If the date column is just string (as opposed to DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP etc) you'd need to do some kind of string comparison

Comment: are you getting all the rows or do you want a specific row?

Comment: Thank you this, makes sense.  I am uploading data to database now in DATE instead of string so I will be testing momentarily.

Comment: @Dagon I will be getting a specific row, each has ID as primary.

Comment: @scibuff that works if the DATE-Column is unique (no two rows with the same date). Suppose it is not unique (For example, because we are not using statistics like it seems to be the case here, but articles released on that day, which can be anything from 0 to n>1), how would you go about it? I know this is a slight derail, but I don't think a new question is necessary for this and I'm interested in the result.

Comment: @malexmave there are several options, eg you could group on DATE and aggregate the data using fuctions such as `SUM`

Comment: @scibuff and if I don't want aggregated data but, for example, all articles from that day, so I would actually get multiple rows of results? Thanks.

Comment: @malexmave then you could either get all the data (without using the `LIMIT` and only use what you need in php) or use a subquery to first find the date and then use that value in your select, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date IN ( SELECT date FROM table WHERE date <= '2012-02-10' LIMIT 1 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date <= "2012-02-10" ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1
```

make sure your DATE column is a date field. And you're good to go!

Replace 2/10/2012 with whatever user inputs in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Hamad I will test here in a min.  Yes I have converted the above to DATE so it is actually '2012-02-10'